# Spring batch multithreading: throttle-limit impact

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a multi-threaded Step configured with a threadpool with a corePoolSize of 48 threads (it's a big machine) but I did not configure the **throttle-limit**.

I am wondering if I have been under utilizaing the machine because of this.

The Spring Batch documentation says that **throttle-limit** is the max amount of concurrent tasks that can run at one time and the **default is 4**.

I can see in **jconsole** that in fact there are 48 threads created and they seem to be executing (I can also see that in my logs).

But, so, even though I can see the 48 threads created, does the **throttle-limit of 4** mean that only 4 of those 48 threads are indeed executing work concurrently?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct i.e. only threads equal to throttle limit be doing work concurrently.

In your case, since its a thread - pool , any four threads could be chosen randomly to do the work and rest of threads will remain idle but since threads get rotated for those four tasks, it will give an impression that all threads are doing work concurrently.

**corePoolSize** simply indicates the number of threads to be started and maintained during job run but that doesn't mean that all are running concurrently what it means that you are trying to avoid thread creation overhead etc during job run.

You have not shared any code or job structure so its hard to point any more specifics.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It does help.